# I can’t load a byte array whose size is more than 8192 bytes via web-api into a MYSQL database

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have a method in the web api that receives two byte arrays (initially images that the user uploads on the site). the first array is 7156 bytes long, the second is 317611 bytes long. The method loads these arrays into a MySQL database, BLOB data type. The first array is loaded into the database fine, but instead of the second array, the database is null.
But if I try to load an image weighing 317611 bytes directly in the database itself (i.e. not through the web api), then it is successfully saved. What is the problem: the database or my web api?

My Web-api method:

```
[HttpPost]
public void SavePictures([FromBody] Request value)
{
    guest.Avatar = value.AvatarBytes;
    guest.Passport = value.PassportBytes;
    _dbContext.Guests.Add(guest);
    _dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

[image: first byte array]
[image: second byte array]

Answer (score 0):

A `BLOB` column can only hold 65,535 bytes. Use `MEDIUMBLOB` for values up to 16,777,215 bytes in length, or `LONGBLOB` for up to 4 GiB. (See [string type storage requirements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/storage-requirements.html) and [BLOB at MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/blob/).)

If your database column is the `BLOB` type, you will need to perform a schema migration to use a larger column type.

If your database column already is the `MEDIUMBLOB` or `LONGBLOB` type, then maybe you have some code that is rejecting values that would be too large for a `BLOB`. Check your EF type mappings to ensure that the right blob type is being used.

Comment: i am scaffolding an existing database with "Scaffold-DbContext "connection-string" MySql.EntityFrameworkCore -OutputDir sakila -f" command. And now i see that there is no code in mapping for blob. I changed the datatype in database from blob to longblob and tried to write code in mapping manually 
`
entity.Property(e => e.Avatar).HasColumnType("longblob");
`
but this didn't help. I also tried that with blob type and it didn't work too